# primefaces command button not showing a confirm dialog until after the second click

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces, command

So I'm pretty new to jsf, I want a confirm dialog to be shown only if an attribute is set to true in my backing bean. I have something like this.

I have a data table which is multi selectable. When you select items in the table, an attribute get sets in the backing bean to hold those items.

Basically what the "showDeleteDialog()" method does, is check to see if any of those items in the list is selected, only then will it show the confirm dialog if the delete button is selected.

So what I want to happen is once a person has selected items from the data table, click the delete button. Have a confirm dialog come up and then delete the selected items. If the user has no items selected from the data table. I want the delete button to not show the confirm dialog.

```
            <p:commandButton
                styleClass="referralTaskDeleteBtn"
                id="deleteButton"
                value="#{loc['RegionAdmin.TaskType.DeleteButton']}"
                icon="ui-icon-close"
                update="deleteConfirmDialog,@this"
                rendered="true"
                action="#{referralTasksController.showDeleteDialog()}"
                oncomplete="if (#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"
                style="visibility: #{referralTasksController.toggleDeleteAndCompleteButtons()};"
                disabled="#{not referralTasksController.enableEditButtons()}"
        >
        </p:commandButton>
```

and the backing bean method

```
    public void showDeleteDialog(){
    if (selectedReferralTasks.size()!=0)
        this.displayDeleteDialog = true;

}
```

Anytime I click this, my dialog box only opens after the second click. Any ideas why? I'll include the dialog in case that is needed. Any help would be appreciate.

```
<p:outputPanel id="confirmationDailogOutputPanel">
            <p:confirmDialog
                    id="deleteConfirmDialog"
                    header="Confirm Delete"
                    message="Are you sure you want to delete the selected Tasks"
                    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                        widgetVar="confirmDailogWidget"
                    >

                <p:commandButton value="#{loc['RegionAdmin.TaskType.DeleteButton']}" styleClass="confirmDialogDeleteButton" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                 action="#{referralTasksController.deleteTasks()}"
                                 oncomplete="PF('confirmDailogWidget').hide();"
                                 update=":#{p:component('NoticePanel')},referralsTaskList,completeButton,deleteButton"
                />
                <p:commandButton value="#{loc['RegionAdmin.TaskType.CancelButton']}"
                                 styleClass="confirmDialogCancelButton"
                                 icon="ui-icon-close"
                                 oncomplete="PF('confirmDailogWidget').hide();"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: to be honest i didn't understand your question the only idea that i have is to try to make an output in your condition and see if he entrer the first time

Comment: Sorry I'll try to explain better

Answer (score 0):

### Problem explanation

In this `oncomplete="if (#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"` part of code you mixed ExpressionLanguage (`#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}`) and JavaScript code (everything else).

So when you load page Expression Language is evaluated (you can put a breakpoint to check this). At the first time when page is loaded of course evaluation return false. The code looks like this  `oncomplete="if (false) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"`. It will never call `show()` method.

When page is reloaded (after button click) Expression Language is once again evaluated. Now code looks like this `oncomplete="if (true) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"` (if you select data in datatable of course). This is a reason why dialog shows on second attempt.

### Solutions

**First: Runtime update**

1. Remove `oncomplete="if (#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"`
2. Change bean method to

   ```
   public void showDeleteDialog(){
       if (selectedReferralTasks.size()!=0){
             RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("confirmDailogWidget.show()");
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. More about this solution you can found in [PF documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf) Misc > Request Context or in [Open  from bean by RequestContext#execute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073580/open-pdialog-from-bean-by-requestcontextexecute)

**Second: Use p:confirmDialog `rendered` parameter**

1. Remove `oncomplete="if (#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}) { PF('confirmDailogWidget').show(); }"`
2. Add `rendered` parameter to `p:confirmDialog` like this `<p:confirmDialog rendered="#{referralTasksController.displayDeleteDialog}"`. Take a look at PF documentation and list of `p:confirmDialog` attributes
3. Change `update` parameter after button click to update `confirmationDailogOutputPanel` like this `<p:commandButton update="confirmationDailogOutputPanel"`. Connected with [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)